# mqtt broker + node js + dht11 sensor

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I have a question about MQTT broker. My code is here and it works with Mosca server.

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var scanf = require('scanf');

var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost');
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString())
  //client.end()
})

client.on('connect', function () {
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log('Please scan data');
    var data = scanf('%s');
    console.log('Message Sent');
    while(data==0){
      client.subscribe('/sensors/#');
      break;
    }
    if(data==1){
      client.unsubscribe("/sensors/#");
    }
  },500);
});
```

I am trying to take sensor data after enter 0 but I entered 0 they come all of them data until that time. Arduino ide  goes on sending data every 500ms but I just want to take data when I entered 0.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with this.

Firstly `scanf('%s')` will block until a enter is pressed which is not what you want inside a `setInterval()` callback.

Next your while loop, it doesn't do what you think it does.

You should only call `client.subscribe('/sensors/#')` once, this tells the client to inform the broker that it this client is to be told about all messages that match the topic "/sensors/#". After that the MQTT client will receive all messages published until `client.unsubscribe('/sensors/#')` is called.

Also since `scanf('%s')` is only called once the `data` will never change
 this means that the loop will either run forever or never run at all depending on what key is pressed.

What you want is something like this:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var scanf = require('scanf');

var data = "0";

var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost');
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  if (data == "1") {
    console.log(message.toString())
  }
})

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('/sensors/#');
});

do {
  data = scanf('%s');
} while (true)
```

This will start and subscribe to topic, it will then wait for you to enter 1, after that it will print every matching message, if you then enter 0 it will stop printing out values until you enter 1 again.

p.s. good MQTT topic design says that topics should not start with a leading '/'